# Import files from outside the project

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm writing two projects, both in js. Webpack and babel are used.
I want to create folder `common` which will contain files, that are used in each project. For example some constants etc.

So I have such a structure:

```
|- project
    |- server
        |- config
           |- webpack.config.js
        |- package.json
        |- .babelrc
        |- ...
    |- client
        |- config
           |- webpack.config.js
        |- package.json
        |- .babelrc
        |- index.js
        |- ...
    |- common
        |- constants
            |- http-codes.js
```

But, it appeared that it's impossible to import files outside the project. eg. it's impossible to do such an import in `client/index.js`: `import * from '../common/constants/http-codes.js'`

Do you have any ideas how such an imports could be done?

---

**Update:**

files:

`common/constants/http-codes.js`:

```
export const SUCCESS = 200;
...
```

---

`client/index.js`:

```
import { SUCCESS } from 'common/constants/http-codes.js';
...
console.log(SUCCESS);
```

---

`client/config/webpack.config.js`:

```
...
const PATHS = {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    build: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
    common: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../common')
};
...
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '', '.js', '.jsx', '.styl' ],
        alias: {
            ...,
            common: PATHS.common
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: `'common/constants/http-codes.js';` Shouldn't that be `'../common/constants/http-codes.js';` ?

Comment: @saadq, It mustn't because I've used webpack's alias.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using *path* module from nodejs?

Comment: It's used in webpack config. But it doesn't help.

Comment: Try using it with **normalize** method, adding *../../* etc.

Comment: Try using `path.normalize('../common/constants/http-codes.js')` in your index.js file