# Why to import Node Modules in React Native

Tags: import, react-native, build, node-modules

inside my main folder i have node_modules folder and two react native projects like that :

- RootFoder

  - ReactNativeProject1
  - ReactNativeProject2
- node_modules
- SharedFolder

  - SharedComponent

i am search for a way to use node_modules folder inside each ReactNativeProject & SharedFolder

and also save the ability to use react-nativd run-ios/run-android for each project
how can i a achieve that ?

Thanks !

Comment: This is a bad idea. Every project has its own dependencies and own modules. This may save your storage but when projects develop further in time, you will regret doing this. For example, one module may require react native 0.35 and other  0.40 because in second one you wanted to use a new feature where the old one cant be updated since other modules have dependency of RN 0.35. What now? And this can go forever

Comment: yes i understand that i need node_modules for each react native project ...
my main issue is how to use shared component for both projects

i tried to import a component from outside of the react native folder and i am getting an error : Unable to resolve module

Comment: OK. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234827/import-files-from-outside-the-project

Comment: i didnt understand how to use webpack with react native

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: i need to use a shared component that each react native project will have access to it